# select from table (laravel) - where and orWhere

Tags: laravel

So, I'm using laravel and I want to make this query to work in laravel 'formula'

```
SELECT * FROM `complaints` WHERE (`fID` = 0) AND (`hide_topic` = 0 OR (`hide_topic` <= 0 OR (`hide_topic` > 3 AND byID = 52))) ORDER BY `status` ASC, `id` DESC
```

And I made something like this in laravel but not sure that selects correctly like the query above does.

```
               DB::table('complaints')
                          ->where('fID', '=', 0)
                                ->where('hide_topic', '=', 0)
                                ->orWhere('hide_topic', '<', 0)
                                ->orWhere('hide_topic', '>', 3)
                                    ->where('byID', '=', 52)
                           ->orderBy('status', 'asc')
                           ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                           ->get();
```

Any help?

Comment: Just debug query, many ways to do that

Comment: Please check laravel's website, these kind of things are already mentioned with explanation in their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you carefully examine your query. You can definitely remove some extra filters. If you see inner where if `hide_topic <= 0` it also covers `hide_topic =0` so you can reduce your query to.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `complaints` 
WHERE `fID` = 0 
    AND (`hide_topic` <= 0 OR (`hide_topic` > 3 AND byID = 52))
ORDER BY `status` ASC, `id` DESC
```

Best thing from laravel is that you can actually see the query that will be executed using query builders or eloquent model using `toSql` method. You can use `toSql` method at place of `get`, `all` or `first` functions.

```
$result = DB::table('complaints')
                ->where('fID', '=', 0)
                ->where(function($query) {
                    $query->where('hide_topic', '<=', 0)
                        ->orWhere(function($query) {
                            $query->where('hide_topic', '>', 3)
                                ->where('byID', '=', 52);
                    });
                })
                ->orderBy('status', 'asc')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')    
                ->get();

// to check the query just replace `->get();` to `->toSql();` in above query.
```

Now if you don't want any modifications in your existing query. You can reference to **@OMR** answer. Still I'll put it here.

```
$result = DB::table('complaints')
                ->where('fID', '=', 0)
                ->where(function($query) {
                    $query->where('hide_topic', '=', 0)
                          ->orWhere(function($query) {
                            $query->where('hide_topic', '<=', 0)
                                ->orWhere(function($query) {
                                    $query->where('hide_topic', '>', 3)
                                        ->where('byID', '=', 52);
                                });
                            });
                })
                ->orderBy('status', 'asc')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')    
                ->get();            -- use toSql() to actually see the query before bindings.
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me about toSQL, and yes, I should remove first hide_topic == 0

Answer (score 0):

you simply use [where with clouser](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses) for every compound condition:

```
   $admin_level=3;
    $playerid=52;

    DB::table('complaints')->where('fID', '=', 0)
        ->where(function ($query)use($admin_level,$playerid){
            $query->where('hide_topic', '=', 0)->orWhere(function ($query)use($admin_level,$playerid){
                $query->Where('hide_topic', '<', 0)->orWhere(function ($query)use($admin_level,$playerid){
                    $query ->Where('hide_topic', '>', $admin_level)
                        ->where('byID', '=', $playerid);
                });
            });
        })
        ->orderBy('status', 'asc')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: you can simply tell the query builder function to use your variables